# Security Questions about Websocket Websites such as Blazor-Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, security, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've currently been using Blazor-Server and absolutely in love with it.
However, I've come to a realization of how a lot of things work "behind the scenes" and now am questioning the security aspects of it...

If we take Microsoft's default Blazor-Server template and visit the "Counter" page, we'll notice it's very simple and has only the following code:

```
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

This page contains one method that can be invoked on a button's click as shown here:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
```

Since a lot of blazor-server magic is going on behind the scenes, a high-level of this interpretation would be "a websocket sending a packet to the server when you click that button".
This makes me worried a little bit due to possible security vulnerabilities.
For example, what if I threw in a tiny if-statement trying to achieve the effect of only admins can see and click this button, like so:

```
@if (user == AdminRole)
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCountAdmin">Click me</button>
}

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    private void IncrementCountAdmin()
    {
        currentCount += 5;
    }
}
```

Since this is simply just sending packet back and forth from client's websocket to server, woudln't any client who has a packet manipulation tool be able to invoke this IncrementCountAdmin method?
This is very troubling to me however maybe there is even more magic behind the scenes of blazor-server that also validates packet some how?

If anyone has any information about this, I'd be greatly appreciated to learn more about blazor-server applications :)

I've been using the default blazor-server application to test + create this example scenario.

Comment: Yes, your backend methods need to verify the user making the request in one way or another. There are many approaches to do this. This is true of all web applications, not limited to this stack.

Comment: So ultimately, you're suggesting moving the validation if-statement inside the method rather than on the rendered page, correct?

Comment: that's all client-side... no websockets.  The UI is not really secured at all.  A user can have complete control over it if they want.  The back-end is what is secured.  So if those were server-side actions being taken, you'd just put the [Authorize] attribute on the endpoint.  That would check for appropriate role.

Answer (score 0):

I can only address you specific question.

The application security you implement depends upon the requirements of your application.  You can implement security in the UI layer and/or in the presentation layer.

In the example you have given, there's only an event wired up to `IncrementCountAdmin` in the Renderer if the button is rendered.  So even if you can get into the SignalR session (difficult) of a normal user,  and try and send a click event to the Renderer, there's no event listener wired up to call `IncrementCountAdmin`.

Comment: There's a Repo of mine that shows how to do authorization at various levels here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Authorization.

Comment: Behind the scenes, there will be a packet that invokes the `IncrementCountAdmin`though, correct? So it seems like all the validation logic should be moved inside the actual method implementation?